# Django Haystack faceting on the model type

Tags: django-haystack, facet

I want to facet the results based on the different model_names (classes) returned.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: can you explain this question more with an example please ?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried adding a `SearchIndex` field with this information? E.g.

```python
class NoteIndex(SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    title = CharField(model_attr='title')
    facet_model_name = CharField(faceted=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Note

    def prepare_facet_model_name(self, obj):
        return "note"


class MemoIndex(SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    title = CharField(model_attr='title')
    facet_model_name = CharField(faceted=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Memo

    def prepare_facet_model_name(self, obj):
        return "memo"
```

And so on, simply returning a different string for each search index. You could also create a mixin and return the name of the model returned by `get_model` too.

Presuming you've added this field to each of your `SearchIndex` definitions, just [chain the `facet` method](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html#determine-facets-and-searchqueryset) to your results.

```python
results = form.search().facet('facet_model_name')
```

Now the `facet_counts` method will return a dictionary with the faceted fields and count of results for each facet value, in this case, the model names.

Note that the field here is labeled verbosely to avoid a possible conflict with `model_name`, a field added by Haystack. It's not faceted, and I'm not sure if duplicating it will cause a conflict.

Comment: Can you explain how this would be used in a single search form to display faceting on multiple models? For example if we had Notes, Memos and Recordings, how each with its own Index, how can I have one FacetedSearchForm show faceting on these distinct models?

Comment: Do you mean each with its own SearchIndex definition?

Comment: Note: do NOT use `model_name` for the SearchIndex field, like I did. This name is used by Haystack internally (at least, within the ElasticSearch backend), and you'll run into a weird-looking error saying `__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'model_name'`. The suggested `faceted_model_name` is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to filter on the model type, you can use the [ModelSearchForm](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0/views_and_forms.html#modelsearchform)

Answer (score 0):

[The Docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html) have a really good walk-through for this.

The minimum you'll need:

1. is to add `faceted=True` to the params of your `model_names` field.
2. Rebuild your schema and indices.
3. add `.facet('model_names')` to whatever SearchQuerySet you're wanting to facet.

More explanation on the question would enable a more complete answer.